# Concatenate column values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to concatenate the values of a column, but the values must be formatted to another string.

Here's my table:

```
 C1         C2                      c3                  c4
---------   ---------               ------              --------
ID1         28-OCT-16 11.59.00      (null)              04-OCT-16 08.48.00
ID2         (null)                  05-OCT-16 02.55.00  (null)  
ID3         (null)                  10-OCT-16 04.32.00  21-OCT-16 02.25.00
ID4         10-OCT-16 04.32.00      18-OCT-16 08.52.00  18-OCT-16 08.32.00
ID5         10-OCT-16 04.32.00      (null)              (null)
```

I've accomplished to format the table to match the value I need.

```
select 
    c1 T_ID,
    case when c2 is not null then 'Plane' end PLANE,
    case when c3 is not null then 'BUS' end BUS,
    case when c4 is not null then 'Hotel' end HOTEL
    from table1 
order by 1;




T_ID        PLANE                   BUS                 HOTEL
---------   ---------               ------              --------
ID1         Plane                   (null)              Hotel
ID2         (null)                  BUS                 (null)  
ID3         (null)                  BUS                 Hotel
ID4         Plane                   BUS                 Hotel
ID5         Plane                   (null)              (null)
```

And i'm trying to do the following

```
T_ID        SERVICE         
---------   ---------       
ID1         Plane+Hotel         
ID2         BUS         
ID3         BUS+Hotel           
ID4         Plane+BUS+Hotel         
ID5         Plane
```

I've tried a couple concatenation functions, but can't find the result I'm looking for.

Comment: "I've tried a couple concatenation functions" - what have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Show us what is the result you are looking for please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do:

```
select c1 T_ID,
       substr( (case when c2 is not null then '+Plane' end) ||
               (case when c3 is not null then '+BUS' end) ||
               (case when c4 is not null then '+Hotel' end)
               2)
from table1 
order by 1;
```

This basically implements the function `concat_ws()` by putting the separator at the beginning of each component in the string.  The outer `substr()` removes the first character.